# Deploy mule domain through MMC RestAPI

Tags: maven, mule, maven-plugin, mule-studio

We are trying to use Mule 3.7.2 with Shared resources (Domains concept). As maven is our build tool , we were successful in building and deploying the apps in MMC using its RESTAPI.
But we are struck in deploying the domain as the REST API is deploying in under /apps folder.

What I read in the blogs, I see the domains cannot be monitored in MMC, which is fine for us now, but we need to deploy through MMC.

Kindly share any ideas on how to deploy the domain through MMC Restapi.

Comment: Is your Mule server running in the same computer that executes your Maven build?

Comment: No, we have a build server where mvn builds, MMC in a box and an ESB in a different box.

Answer (score 0):

MMC does not support domains deployments. MMC is replaced by Anypoint Runtime Manager. You may use [Anypoint Runtime Manager agent](https://docs.mulesoft.com/runtime-manager/runtime-manager-agent), to deploy domains through its [REST API](https://docs.mulesoft.com/runtime-manager/managing-applications-and-domains) (which you must enable as part of the agent configuration).